# Как узнать в python когда заканчивается месяц?

Tags: python-3.x

Как узнать в python когда заканчивается месяц?

Comment: Начинается первого числа каждого месяца. Что значит "когда"?

Comment: @vp_arth да заканчивается

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42950/2110496

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import calendar
>>> calendar.monthrange(2018, 7)
(6, 31)
```

6 - День недели первого дня, воскресенье
31 - Число дней в месяце

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще несколько вариантов из [аналогичного вопроса на англоязычном SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950/get-last-day-of-the-month-in-python):

варант 1:

```
import datetime

def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)  # this will never fail
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)
```

варант 2:

```
import datetime

datetime.date (2000, 2, 1) - datetime.timedelta (days = 1)
```

варант 3:

```
def last_day_of_month(date):
    if date.month == 12:
        return date.replace(day=31)
    return date.replace(month=date.month+1, day=1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```